# Start-process: both positional parameter and can't locate file specified

Tags: powershell, deployment, remote-access

Ok, So I am working on the powershell remote deployment of software to ADUsers.
I have remote access to the computer and all, no problems there.

Right now I am at the point where I have a exe file from Ninite to just install 7zip onto the client pc just to see when it works so i can start deploying some bigger programs to it.

The guide I have found to help me deploy out the software for now looks like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName *REDACTED* -Scriptblock {
    Start-Process C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ninite_7_zip\Ninite 7Zip Installer.exe '/silent' -wait
}
```

When I do run this code, I get the error:

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Installer.exe'.

So I thought to myself, that it might be because of the spaces in the name. So therefore I changed it to:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName *REDACTED* -Scriptblock {
        Start-Process C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ninite_7_zip\Ninite_7Zip_Installer.exe '/silent' -wait
    }
```

And ofcourse also changed it's name within the folder to match the "newly made" code.

But the error now changed into:

> This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified

Even though I use Powershell ISE, and I used it's guideboxes when writing, to enter the folder and find it, when I wrote the directory.

My only goal in this, is that I want to remotely run and complete this installer on the client PC when deployed from the DC upon which the file lies.

Anybody got a qualified guess? Or maybe even so, a solution.

Thanks in advance for your kind answers.

Comment: Then why not use the path in UNC format to the share on the DC _upon which the file lies_? Something like `Start-Process '\\Server\DeploymentShare\ninite_7_zip\Ninite_7Zip_Installer.exe' '/silent' -wait`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I do run this code, I get the error:
>
> > A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Installer.exe'.

You'll want to use quotation marks to qualify path names with spaces in them:

```
Start-Process 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ninite_7_zip\Ninite 7Zip Installer.exe' '/silent' -wait
```

> But the error now changed into:
>
> > This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Even though I use Powershell ISE, and I used it's guideboxes when writing, to enter the folder and find it, when I wrote the directory.

ISE is not smart enough to realize that the scriptblock is to be executed on a remote computer, so it completes the path based on *your local file system*.

You still need to copy the executable to the remote machine in order to execute it:

```bsh
# first copy the installer to remote file system
$remoteSession  = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computerName
$localInstaller = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ninite_7_zip\Ninite 7Zip Installer.exe'
$remotePath     = Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock { $env:TEMP }
Copy-Item $localInstaller -Destination (Join-Path $remotePath "7zInstaller.exe") -ToSession $remoteSession

# now we can invoke the executable on the remote machine (re-using the same remoting session)
Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock {
  Start-Process (Join-Path $env:TEMP "7zInstaller.exe") '/silent' -Wait
}

# clean up
$remoteSession |Remove-PSSession |Out-Null
```

Comment: after making the thread and working on it, i also realised that it was the missing " that was the problem around the path file to the file, and that i was looking at the wrong file, and it never was on the client pc. 

the code you wrote here still ends up giving me the error:

> Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

Comment: also, the { $env:TEMP } what does that do? never seen it before

Comment: @Mikeskovby `$env:Temp` resolves the value of the `%TEMP%` environment variable (try it for yourself!). Reason for doing this on the remote machine is that it might be different from the temp path on your local system/session

Comment: WRT the error, I forgot to include `-Scriptblock` before the argument, I've updated the answer now

Comment: after adjusting the change, it seems it isn't installing it on the client pc, since I ran the code, it went through without errors or anything (thanks alot!), but i still do not have 7zip installed on the client pc

Comment: When you say "client pc", are you talking about the remote computer that you're trying to execute the installer on, or your own local machine (the one from which you run `Invoke-Command`)?

Comment: I mean the remote pc that i am trying to run the installer on

Comment: @Mikeskovby Well, remove the `/silent` argument if you don't actually want it to fail silently :)

Comment: mhm... still get no errors or anything from it. it justs ends the script with nothing to say and "nothing" happened. 
well, I can't take up your entire time, so I will look up this on my own.
Can't thank you enough for this though